# Leave one out cross validation in kernel density estimation

Tags: nonparametric, density-estimation, nonparametric-density

I am taking a look at :
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jerryzhu/cs731/kde.pdf

Where they define the following loss function for kernel density estimates

$$J(h) = \int \hat{f_n}^2(x)dx -2\int\hat{f_n}(x)f(x)dx$$
which comes from expanding the loss
$$\int(\hat{f_n}(x)-f(x))^2dx$$
called the **integrated square loss**. This loss makes intiuitive sense to me because they are asking, how well did our kernel density match the true density.

However, I am unable to follow the next step. They claim we can re-write $J(h)$ as 
$$\hat{J(h)} =  \int\hat{f_n}^2(x)-\frac{2}{n}\sum\hat{f_{-i}}(x_i)$$
meaning we approximate $J(h)$ with a leave-one-out approach (that is what the notation $f_{-i}$ means).

I really don't understand the intuition behind this. Can anyone help clarify?

Thanks!

Comment: The identity (in expectation, anyways) in question was uncovered simultaneously in a pair of famous papers by Bowman and Rudemo in the early 1980s. Like many great ideas, it's obvious once you know it's true -- but it was not obvious to several generations of statisticians who came before then, including quite a few brilliant ones! So don't feel bad if you do not immediately see it.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing your formulas, we have
\begin{align}
J(h) & \approx \hat{J(h)} & \implies \\
\int\!\!\hat{f_n}(x)f(x)dx & \approx \tfrac{1}{n}\sum_i\hat{f}_{\!\!-i}(x_i) & \implies \\
\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{f_n}(x)\right] &\approx \overline{\hat{f}_{\!\!-i}(x_i)}
\end{align}
which says that the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_continuous_random_variable) of the full kernel estimate is approximately equal to the [sample average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance#Sample_mean) of the "leave the evaluation point out" kernel estimate.

Does this help the intuition?

Comment: it does, but why leave-one-out? why not full sample average?

Comment: Well, the point is to do cross-validation (i.e. the formula is not advertised as a training error?). As I understand it, the $\hat{f}_{-i}$ kernel-density excludes the basis function centered @ point $x_i$. Each term in the 2nd sum is the [likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) of a point under the kernel-density based on the other points, so when the average leave-one-out likelihood is high, the CV error is low. (For example, if a point is an outlier relative to its nearest-neighbor + bandwidth, it will have a low likelihood, so not contribute much to the sum).

Comment: Sorry I realized I never framed this discussion properly, I think the point is bandwith choice, so it is training error in that minimizing the error with respect to bandwith yields optimal bandwith

Comment: Well first of all, the sum **is** a full-sample average, just an average of $\hat{f}_{-i}$ rather than $\hat{f}_n$. In terms of  bandwidth, the "missing terms" would just "want" $h\to{0}$, to put all the probability mass of their kernel $K_i(x)$ at *their* sample point $x_i$, no?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is how leave-one-out cross validation works. Let's assume we have ten data points {x1,x2,...,x10}. Every time we train the bandwidth without only one point which will be used for validation purpose. I agree with you that we do the training and aim to minimize the error, but we may face an over-fitting issue and that's the reason why we apply cross-validation. Actually, it is full sample average; otherwise, the second term in J(h)^ should be divided by n-1 instead of n. In the ten data points example, we will train ten times and each time we have 9 training points and 1 validation point. Here n=10.